# Para que se usan los Claim Sub y Aud del Payload en un sistema con Json Web Token

Tags: autenticación, jwt

Estoy realizando pruebas para entender e implementar un sistema de autorización de usuarios a través del uso de *Json Web Token*.

Buscando información acerca de la configuración de un token me surge un par de dudas acerca del uso de dos Claim del Payload, el Sub y el Aud.

```
{
    "iss": "www.miweb.com", // emisor
    "iat": 1455550200, // emitido en
    "exp": 1455559810, // expira
    "nbf": 1455550260, // no usar antes de
    "jti": "31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0", // id único

    "sub": "", // ¿asunto?
    "aud": "", // ¿?

    "data": {/* datos anexos */}
}
```

Por lo que he observado se usan poco estos dos claim. Mi pregunta entonces es:

**¿En que escenario se puede dar su uso y con que objetivo?**

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos

Pd.: La misma pregunta está en StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37634140/6272471

Comment: Respondieron en StackOverflow y publico la respuesta también aquí. Espero que la traducción sea lo más fiel posible a la respuesta original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondido por [MvdD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18044/mvdd) en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37635391/6272471)

---

El claim asunto (1) (`'sub'`) identifica al usuario o aplicación (en el caso del flujo de credenciales del cliente (2) que ha sido autentificada. El claim audiencia (3) (`'aud'`) indica para que se emite el token.

Supongamos que mi aplicación cliente tiene que llamar al `servicio A` en nombre del `usuario X`.

Por lo general, mi solicitud se comunicaría con el servidor de autorización para autenticar al usuario (por ejemplo, usando uno de los flujos de subvención OAuth2(4)) y solicitar acceso al `servicio X`. El servidor de autorización podría autenticar al usuario y pedir consentimiento.

Si el usuario da su consentimiento, el servidor de autorización emitirá un token JWT con un claim asunto único para el `usuario X` y un claim audiencia indicando `servicio A`.

> *Links de referencia:*
>   (1) tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2
>   (2) tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.4
>   (3) tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3
>   (4) tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.2

Comment: He puesto los enlaces de referencias abajo como texto plano. Aún no me deja poner más de dos enlaces. Espero que sirva. Saludos,